# Prob using axes for subplot an get AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'plot'

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot, axes

'''
matplotlib.use("Qt5Agg")

```
pas = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

# set up l'organisation de la figure
fig, axs = plt.subplots(nrows=3,ncols=len(pas))


manager = plt.get_current_fig_manager()
manager.window.showMaximized()
plt.show()
     
axs[1, 0+1].set(ylabel='fréquence (set test)')
for iii in range(0, len(pas)):
    
    bins = np.linspace(round(y[:,iii].min()), round(y[:,iii].max()), 20)
    axs[0, iii].hist(yhat_graph[:,iii], bins, color = 'steelblue', alpha = 0.5, label='simulation')
    axs[0, iii].hist(y[:,iii], bins, color = 'orange', alpha=0.5, label='ref. apport hist.')
    axs[0, iii].set(xlabel='apports m3/sec')

    axs[0, iii].legend(loc='upper right')
    axs[0, iii].set(title='prévision J+'  + str(iii+1) + ' (set test)' )
    

axs[1, 0].set(ylabel='Variations journalières Jn - Jn-1 (set test) \n observation')
for iii in range(0, len(pas)-1):
    axs[1, iii].plot()
    graph_scatter(ecart_valid_y[iii],
                  ecart_yhat[iii], True,'simulation','','var. j' + str(iii+1) +' - j ' + str(iii) ,'steelblue')
    axs[1, iii].set(xlabel='simulation')


if history == 'missing':
    print('pas de fichier history')
    axs[2,0:].plot()
else:
    axs[2, 0].plot()
    graph_loss(history)
    axs[2,1:].plot()

graph_sim_multiStep(y[-windowGraph[0]:-windowGraph[1]], yhat_graph[-windowGraph[0]:-windowGraph[1]], nash, kge, titre)
```

'''

with this line "axs[2,1:].plot()"

I've got this error:
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'plot'

the function 'graph_loss' and 'graph_scatter' work fine lonely

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you say, the problem is with this line:

```
axs[2,1:].plot()
```

In your code, `axs` is a 3x10 numpy array of `AxesSubplot` objects. I assume what you're trying to do is to call the `plot()` method on several of those objects at once, but numpy arrays don't support method calls like that. You could look at the `vectorize()` method, but I think it's clearest to just use a for loop. Here's a small example that calls `plot()` with some data on a couple of subplots, then calls `plot()` with no parameters on the rest of the subplots.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, axs = plt.subplots(nrows=2,ncols=3)

axs[0, 0].plot([1, 4, 2])
axs[0, 2].plot([4, 1, 2])

# Could probably remove the next three lines.
axs[0, 1].plot()
for iii in range(3):
    axs[1, iii].plot()

plt.show()
```

I only wonder why you want to call `plot()` with no parameters in the first place. It just seems to change the axis scale a bit. Try removing those calls completely.

Comment: I create a script to create complexe custum graph, I wish t generate the subplots and fill it by the graph of my script